# How does the metric for Most Successful Heroes differ from "Performance" in Heroes Played?

Tags: dota-2

On my profile page, the **Most Successful Heroes** list Silencer, Spirit Breaker and Mirana.

[image: Most Successful Heroes: Silencer, Spirit Breaker and Mirana]

However, on **Heroes Played** sorted by "Performance", there are heroes that I have a better performance with:

[image]

How do these two metrics relate?

Comment: It looks like "most successful heroes" are just the heroes with the flat number of most wins. I'm guessing that "performance" is probably a more complicated algorithm that factors in KDA and other stuff too, especially since Valve just announced that a visible Hero MMR stat is coming soon. Just my conjecture, though.

Comment: Ah that might be it. I've just seen this related question: [How does performance index work?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/64869/23959), which doesn't cover "Most Successful Heroes", though.

Comment: do one more liich game  and check if he replaces the mirana ;)

Comment: @RayofCommand: Another win on Lich did replace Mirana with Lich on the Most Successful Tab:   http://i.stack.imgur.com/u6qTS.png
  http://i.stack.imgur.com/NDTof.png

Comment: @cloudymusic: Since Lich replaced Mirana with another win, I suspect you are right concerning the flat number of wins on Most Successful Heroes. Which then would make my question for all purposes a duplicate of the one I linked above.

Comment: I've started a bounty on the linked question to get an answer there.